# Proof verification: Closure of integral function.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose we define the $\alpha$-level quantile of a random variable $X$ as
\begin{align}
q_{\alpha}(X) := \inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \{c \ | \ P(X\leq c) \geq \alpha\}
\end{align}
We consider the space $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ (with $P(\Omega) = 1$) and the aim is to show the following:

If $X_k$ is a sequence of random variables in $\mathcal{L}^2$ and $X$ is a random variable in $\mathcal{L}^2$ such that $\|X_k-X\|_ 2 \rightarrow 0$ and for each $k$, $$\int_{\alpha}^{1}q_{\beta}(X_k) \ d\beta \leq 0,$$ then it holds that $$\int_{\alpha}^{1}q_{\beta}(X) \ d\beta \leq 0.$$

What I have tried so far:

Since $X_k$ converges to $X$ in $\mathcal{L}^2$, it converges also in $\mathcal{L}^1$ by Hölder's inequality.

We therefore have that $E[|X_k-X|] \rightarrow 0$, so it follows that $|E[X_k -X]| \rightarrow 0$ using Jensen's inequality.

Using the fact that $$\int_{0}^{1}q_{\beta}(X_k) \ d\beta = E[X_k]$$ we get that

\begin{align}
 |E[X_k] - E[X]| = \Big|\int_{0}^{1}q_{\beta}(X_k) \ d \beta -\int_{0}^{1}q_{\beta}(X) \ d\beta \Big| \rightarrow 0
\end{align}

Could we argue along these lines, or have I missed something? Perhaps there is some simple way to probe the claim?